# S3 sink record field TimeBasedPartitioner not working

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to deploy s3 sink connector where s3 partitions needs to be based on a field coming in data **props.eventTime**

Following is my config :

```
{
  "name" : "test_timeBasedPartitioner",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
  "partition.duration.ms": "3600000",
  "s3.region": "us-east-1",
  "topics.dir": "dream11",
  "flush.size": "50000",
  "topics": "test_topic",
  "s3.part.size": "5242880",
  "tasks.max": "5",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "locale": "en",
  "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
  "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
  "schema.generator.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator",
  "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
  "rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "1800000",
  "path.format": "'EventDate'=YYYYMMdd",
  "s3.bucket.name": "test_bucket",
  "partition.duration.ms": "86400000",
  "timestamp.extractor": "RecordField",
  "timestamp.field": "props.eventTime"
}
```

Following is my sample json that is present in kafka topic :

```
{
    "eventName": "testEvent",
    "props": {
        "screen_resolution": "1436x720",
        "userId": 0,
        "device_name": "1820",
        "eventTime": "1565792661712"
    }
}
```

And the exception that I am getting is :

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:546)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:302)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:205)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1564561484906" is malformed at "4906"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.doParseMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:187)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:826)
    at io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner$RecordFieldTimestampExtractor.extract(TimeBasedPartitioner.java:281)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.executeState(TopicPartitionWriter.java:199)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.write(TopicPartitionWriter.java:176)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask.put(S3SinkTask.java:195)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:524)
    ... 10 more
```

Is there something that I am missing here to configure?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field `props.eventTime` is coming in as **microsecond and not millisecond**.

This can be identified in the stack trace and by inspecting the relevant code in [org.joda.time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeParserBucket.java#L178) `doParseMillis` method, which is [used](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/blob/master/partitioner/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/partitioner/TimeBasedPartitioner.java#L293) by the Connector partitioner `TimeBasedPartitioner` and its timestamp extractor from message payload  `RecordFieldTimestampExtractor` when the `timestamp.field` is a `STRING`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1564561484906" is malformed at "4906"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.doParseMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:187)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:826)
    at io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner$RecordFieldTimestampExtractor.extract(TimeBasedPartitioner.java:281)
```

You could follow one of these solutions:

1. Write your own TimestampExtractor to support microsecond. You can check how to write a custom `TimestampExtractor` [here](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/developer-guide.html).
2. Change/Transform your source data to include a field that comes in with millisecond instead of microsecond
3. Followup on some [issues](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/issues) where default TimestampExtractor flexibility is discussed and suggest/contribute to have it support your use case.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, I did implement custom timestamp extractor, but when I deploy to the cluster task fail saying "CustomTimeStampExtractor does not implement TimestampExtractor"
Import statements are as follows : 
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TimestampExtractor;

Comment: Hi Vikas, it seems your `CustomTimeStampExtractor` class is not implementing `TimestampExtractor` interface. It only has one method called `extract`. You can see a very simple example here: https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/developer-guide.html

Comment: Also, be sure to check the javadocs for TimestampExtractor interface for your specific Kafka Version. The latest version (Kafka 2.3.0) is here: https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/TimestampExtractor.html

Comment: @AlexandreJuma, I think the example you shared is for Kafka stream. However, S3 sink connector needs TimestampExtractor for Kafka connect. Source codes are always good examples --- https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/blob/master/partitioner/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/partitioner/TimeBasedPartitioner.java